# Multiple Reads to Database - Is there a way to create common routine?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, methods

I'm developing an application which requires many passes against tables in the same database. I find myself repeating code (connection open, defining a reader and `SqlCommmand` code) and testing for if the reader has rows.

Is there a way to develop a common routine to pass the SQL string and `AddWithValue` command parameters from multiple places and simply return `myReader` with the results (or a flag indicating no matches found)?

The SQL is easy because it will fit in a string, but all of the `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue` lines are a little more difficult because there will be a different number of them depending on each call to the routine and the casting may be different in the variables passed.

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: Consider passing a collection of strongly-typed parameters, each with the desired value, to a shared routine.  Then add those to the command parameter collection.